# Select com usuários que mais enviaram mensagens

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Estou fazendo um sistema e tenho que saber qual o usuário que mais enviou mensagens. Minhas tabelas estão mais ou menos assim:

**Usuario**

```
id|nome|sobrenome|email| ...
```

**Mensagens**

```
id|uid|nome|email|assunto|msg| ...
```

Eu só preciso saber qual o usuário enviou mais mensagens,

Desde ja, agradeço :)

Comment: Existe o [`count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) para retornar a quantidade de linhas, acho que seria suficiente.

Comment: Ta, mas pra retornar do maior pro menor? Tipo, qual usuario que mais enviou mensagens e qual o que enviou menos ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar o `count`:

```
Select
u.id,
u.nome,
count(m.id) as qtd_mensagens
from mensagens m
inner join usuario u on u.id = m.uid
group by u.id, u.nome
order by qtd_mensagens desc
```

Documentação da função:
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

e se quiser apenas o usuário que mais enviou, você pode limitar os resultados a apenas uma linha, usando o `limit`

```
Select
u.id,
u.nome,
count(m.id) as qtd_mensagens
from mensagens m
inner join usuario u on u.id = m.uid
group by u.id, u.nome
order by qtd_mensagens desc
limit 1
```

Documentação da sintaxe:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado

Comment: @RobertJunio não se esqueça de marcar como resposta. Bem vindo ao StackOverflow pt e faça o tour da comunidade: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour